# Finding and sorting string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, sorting

```
data_set = ["This is cool jacket","I have two white shirts","I need black leather jacket", "I have five half shirts"]
shirt_list = []
jacket_list = []
def parse_data(clothes):
 for i in clothes:
   if "Jacket" in data_set:
     jacket_list.append(i)
   elif "shirt" in data_set:
     shirt_list.append(i)
   else:
     pass
 return shirt_list,jacket_list
print(parse_data(data_set))
```

I need to sort and collect the data from particular string for ex- in the code I need Jacket string to be printed in Jacket_list similarly for shirts. I tried with this code its not working.

Comment: Your description of the problem isn't really good. What exactly about it is not working? Include it. How exactly do you want the output to be like? Include it. You can always edit your question to address these issues.

Comment: Has any of the answers shown to correct the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick fix to your problem is this:

```
data_set = ["This is cool jacket","I have two white shirts","I need black leather jacket", "I have five half shirts"]
shirt_list = []
jacket_list = []
def parse_data(clothes):
 for i in clothes:
   if "jacket" in i:
     jacket_list.append(i)
   elif "shirt" in i:
     shirt_list.append(i)
   else:
     pass
 return shirt_list,jacket_list
print(parse_data(data_set))
```

The reason being is that you are trying to look in the total list, Instead look at each `i`

I would then change your check to more of a universal check like so:

```
if "JACKET" in i.upper():
     jacket_list.append(i)
   elif "SHIRT" in i.upper():
     shirt_list.append(i)
```

this will help eliminate the chances for changes in the list

**Edit:**

If you want to also check for black, this is what you can do:

```
for i in clothes:
   if "jacket" in i:
    if "black" in i:
        jacket_list.append(i)
   elif "shirt" in i:
    if "black" in i:
        shirt_list.append(i)
   else:
     pass
```

All it's doing is adding an extra if statement inside, might be a little more code, but I think it's easier to read.

If you do want it on the same if statement just add this:

`if "jacket" in i and "black" in i:`

Comment: @AbhishekBhosale no problem!

Comment: Hey @Derek Baxter what If I want to find 2 common keywords for ex in above code if I have data set: **"I need black Jacket","I need black Shirt"** and now I want to find both Jacket  and black and sort how would I do it. I tried using _and_ but it didn't work

Comment: @AbhishekBhosale Hey, I edited my answer and added in the extra information, check it out

Comment: Hey @Derek Baxter thanks for the update I was able to do that bit correctly with **("JACKET" and "BLACK") in i.upper()**.` `

Comment: @Dexter Baxter Right now I am facing the problem where I am trying to sort multiple keywords in different data sets and its not happening as it should.

Comment: Hey can i get your mail id so that I can send my code

Comment: @AbhishekBhosale unfortunately I have already answered this question. If you have more problems you should create a new question